# How to auto return to original column but next row when # is scanned

Tags: excel, vba

I want to continuously scan barcodes into excel. Each scan will go into the same row separate cell until "$" is scanned and return to original column and next row.

I have tried this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 3                              'column c
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Select  'move right
            End If
        Case 4                              'column d
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Select  'move right
            End If
        Case 5                              'column E
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Offset(1, -2).Select 'move down and back to column C
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Scan As Variant

Scan = Trim(Target.Value)
If Len(Scan) And Target.Column > 2 Then
    If Left(Scan, 1) = "$" Then
        Scan = Mid(Scan, 2)
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With
        If Target.Column > 3 Then
            Target.ClearContents
            Set Target = Cells(Target.Row + 1, 3)
        End If
        Target.Value = Scan
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If

    Target.Offset(0, Sgn(Val(Scan))).Select
End If
```

End Sub

The code was expanded to include the new requirements as per your comment.

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to have it look for any value at scan that begins with "$" and ends with 3 digits. example "$123". this will return to original column and advance to next row and leave just "123" in the first cell of the new row?